# IF syntax in powershell struggle

Tags: powershell

Can you guys work it out. I'm pretty sure it's just minor syntax error cause i'm noob at this... I'm always getting "Wrong file" no matter what input($name) is.

```
$name = "DE123456.zip"
if ($name -contains "DE") 
{
  Get-ChildItem C:\test\$name | 
   % {
     $to  = $_.basename.length - 2
     $path = $_.basename.substring( 0, $to)
     & "C:\test\7z.exe" "x" "-y" $_.fullname "-oC:\test\$path"
     }
  }
ELSE
{
"Wrong file"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A syntax error would be emitted *before* your script ran.

Your problem is that `-contains` as an operator only checks for existence of values *in an array*. You want the `.Contains` method on the string instead:

```
if ($name.Contains('DE')) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ($name -contains "DE")
```

with

```
if ($name -match "DE")
```

and:

```
get-help about_comparison_operators
```

to know the difference.